# Install dependencies selectively from a local folder

Tags: apt

I have a folder with a dozen of packages, along with the one I want to install, and it's dependencies.

How can I selectively (no `dpkg -i *.deb`) and **easily** install the package with apt ?

Comment: Copy packages to cache or use http://askubuntu.com/a/84323/158442

Comment: @muru I have already checked out that question, but this answer had slipped. I'll try it.